# How do I remove ^null$ errors from Logwatch?

Tags: linux, debian, https, logwatch

After the site is migrated to HTTPS, ^null$-errors are displayed in Logwatch (the connection is closed until the server receives a response) for all hosts that access the site.

How can I remove this error?

In the Logwatch email report:

```
*.** MB transferred in 7645 responses (1xx 7645, 2xx 0, 3xx 0, 4xx 0, 5xx 0)
...
^null$ 2359 Time(s)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the wrong Apache log format. I changed apache2.conf file to the default log-format and Logwatch started working correctly:

```
LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\""
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `.\^null\$.` to `/etc/logwatch/conf/ignore.conf`.

An alternative approach would be to edit `scripts/services/http` (under /usr/share/logwatch by default), find the line `my @exploits = (` and delete the line with `'^null$'` following it, but that will be overridden on updates.